# Trouble expanding image for 100% of browser height with CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I want to expand the hero image for **100%** of the browser **HEIGHT**.

This is what I have:

```
.home-splash {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://www.matthewkosloski.me/hero-3a.jpg") center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

With this code, the hero image (or splash image) only expands to the height of the header.  However, this problem can be avoided (somewhat) by using `width: 100vh;`.  I don't like that because on mobile devices, the height of the hero image is really large... like 5000px in height.  I just want it to expand the EXACT height of the browser.

Here is the jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/E7rDG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the `html`/`body` elements to `100%`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vJvU/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh!  That's a great solution.  I'll be sure to include that in my CSS reset for the future. ;)